# What are the corrections need to be done to the below statements in order to make them work properly in Verilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog

```
int t=-1'd1; //trying to assign -1 to t;
bit vb[7:0]; // simple declaration

bit matrix[0:1][0:7]='{'{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},'{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},'{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},'{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},'{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},'{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},'{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},'{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};// initialising multi-dimensional array.
```

I am using *QuestaSim* to compile and simulate.
this is the report:

```
# -- Compiling module test
# ** Error: (vlog-13032) test.v(8): near "=": Syntax error.
# ** Error: (vlog-13032) test.v(9): near ";": Syntax error.
```

I am somewhat New to the Verilog. Please help me in fixing these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are writing SystemVerilog code in a file with `*.v` file extension. `bit` and `int` are SystemVerilog types that do not exist in Verilog.

Change your file extension to `*.sv` or use `reg` and `integer` types instead.